# Jquery mobile - focus on text input in form in panel causes scroll to top of form in chrome for android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, input, scroll

I'm using jquery mobile so that a div opens up in an overlay panel on the left of my app. The div contains a form.

On chrome for android (on LG V10 and Oneplus 1) when I scroll down to the lower text inputs & focus on them, window scrolls to the top of the document so I can't see the active input. How can I fix this so that focusing on an input doesn't force a scroll to top? I'm using jquery.mobile-1.4.2 & jquery-1.9.1.

form looks like this:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="form_div" data-display="push">

    <form action="thank_you.php" id="form" class="ui-mini">     
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input required name="firstname" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini">

        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input required name="lastname" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini">

        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input required name="email" type="email" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini">

        <label class="phone" >Phone Number</label>
        <input name="phone" type="tel" required pattern="(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}">

        <input name="" type="submit" value="click to submit">
    </form>

</div>
```